# PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function setCustomerId() on a non-object in . /app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php

Tags: magento-1.9, php

> This occurs when a customer clicks the forgotten password link on the
>   front end; they are sent an email with a link to click and when they
>   click the link in the email, a blank white page is shown in the
>   browser or an internal server error such as the following:
>
> Server error The website encountered an error while retrieving
>   https://www.example.co.nz/customer/account/resetpassword/?id=1271&token=b0e401762edadb425d4cdf65dd412bf9.
>   It may be down for maintenance or configured incorrectly. Here are
>   some suggestions: Reload this web page later. HTTP Error 500 (Internal
>   Server Error): An unexpected condition was encountered while the
>   server was attempting to fulfill the request.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The solution of above error is very simple. Just remove the
>   customer.xml file used by your theme from
>   /app/design/frontend///layout/. By
>   doing this Magento will use the customer.xml file from the
>   base/default theme.
>
> If you have did some useful changes in customer.xml file according to
>   your theme and not able to remove that file then update your
>   customer.xml file by putting the under given section in it.

```
<customer_account_resetpassword translate="label">
    <label>Reset a Password</label>
    <remove name="right"/>
    <remove name="left"/>

    <reference name="head">
        <action method="setTitle" translate="title" module="customer">
            <title>Reset a Password</title>
        </action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <template>page/1column.phtml</template>
        </action>
        <action method="setHeaderTitle" translate="title" module="customer">
            <title>Reset a Password</title>
        </action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="customer/account_resetpassword" name="resetPassword" template="customer/form/resetforgottenpassword.phtml"/>
    </reference>
</customer_account_resetpassword>
```

> That’s it.Now see the result, the error will go away.

Comment: Thank you but it's not working from my end @Umesh Kumar

Comment: You must make sure that you clear all of your cache for this change to take effect @Randhir

Comment: Yes, Now working fine, thank you once again @Umesh